# Updating item in CoreData doesn't refresh tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a little problem and tried everything to figure it out. I know the problem but I don't know how to solve it. I'm using CoreData with a fetchedResultsController. My entity is called "name" and the SortDescriptor is also for "name".
If I have one single Item saved to CoreData and change the name value, FetchedResultsController calls .move instead of .update and the label in my TableView doesn't get updated. After restarting the Application or changing a different value of the Item, name is also updated.
If I have more than one Item saved to CoreData everything works without any problems.

How to keep the SortDescriptor on "name" but also update the value in my tableView.

Thanks

Comment: Check the indexPath and newIndexPath in the .move call.  If they are the same, update the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to put: `self.tableView.reloadData()` in the right place.

Comment: Thanks, I've forgotten to put tableView.reloadData() into the .move case. Thought that tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() will take care of that. I checked if the indexPath == newIndexPath and reloaded the tableView. Else moved the row.

Comment: Now, just to optimise it further you can try to update it at the right cell index value of the needed section. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to subscribe to name property of our data item via KVO. Just add your cell as observer and update your UI elements as soon as your data object is changed.

NB. Don't forget to unsubscribe in prepareForReuse